# Get the index number of first and last options listed in drop down menu

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to find the options listed first and last in a dropdown menu using selenium webdriver.

```
li class="dropdown location"

ul class="select"


<li> class="dropdown location"

<ul> class="select"

<li> data-site="http://www.example.com" value="ES">Europe</li>

<li> data-site ="http://www.example.com" value="SG">Singapore</li>
```

There are more than 50 options. I wanted to find the index number of 
Singapore. Is there a way to find that in Webdriver?

Comment: Sure! Which one of the *numerous* methods have you tried? What did not work for you?

Comment: I tried list method to get all the 50 + options and print them in the console. But I am finding difficulties in getting the index of say nth menu. By 50 options I mean there are more than 50 countries options listed and not methods.

Comment: Please have a very careful read through [ask], and edit your post adding **your code** and an explanation of what exactly you are having problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is way to find index of particular value.

Get all options of list.
Compare the text of each element of list  with describable text, see below

```
Select sel = new   Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[title='Sort By']")));

List<WebElement> list = sel.getOptions();

for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
  if(list.get(i).getText().equals("Price")){
    System.out.println("The index of the selected option is: "+i);
    break;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sel = new   Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[title='Sort    By']")));
List<WebElement> list = sel.getOptions();
int index = 0;

foreach(WebElement option : list)
{
    if(option.getText().equals("price"))
    {
        index = list.indexOf(option);
        break;
    }
}
```